# EF6 : How to run re seed while creating Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to seed my database with data. It has ID column in which I want same values as seed code ID column in migration code.
But after code first migration and seeding, tables have different values than seed values.
MS SQL Server database automatically change the values.
For example it starts records from 7, not from 1.

For now, I manually running command in sql server database tables wherever need:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('itemtypes', RESEED, 0) 
GO
```

Is there a good way to do this, so that we ensure the id column begins with 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your code-first migration with [DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx), then I think your values for `Id` as specified in the seed configuration will be ignored by database.